# how to apply different styles to Modal.Header for React-Bootstrap Modal component?

Tags: css, react-bootstrap, react-modal

I'm new to React.

I'm trying to create 2 different styles of Modals with the React-Bootstrap Modal component: one with an orange header, and another white header (aka no header).

[2 types of headers img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3C7g.png)

The style of modal used depends on where it's used. For example, I want the white header to appear for sign in and sign out, and only those 2 modals. Right now, the .modal-header CSS seems like the **default** style applied to any declaration of Modal.Header. My modal-header class has styling for the orange header:

```
.modal-header {
  color: #fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(255deg, #f9b25e, #f17b30);
}
```

I don't want this style applied to the sign up and sign in modals. I tried creating this new CSS ID modal-no-header and adding it to the Modal.Header declaration in the signup and signout js files:

in my CSS:

```
    #modal-no-header{
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

in SignupModal.js:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={this.props.showModal} onHide={this.props.closeModal} >
        <Modal.Header id="modal-no-header" closeButton>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body> blah... <Modal.Body>
     </Modal>
    )
}
```

However, the #modal-no-header styling isn't overriding the default .modal-header class:

[not working, inspect element screenshot included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft1o8.png)

**Question:** Is this the right way to specify multiple styles for Modal components in React-Bootstrap? If not, is there a better method and how do you go about it? I checked out the documentation but wasn't able to spot anything helpful. Thanks in advance.